# JQuery - Fade out text before chaning the texts text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a picture that coverers the whole screen. Every 5 second the background image change to another one with a transition. To this, I have a header with some nice text. When the picture is changing I want to fade out my text and then fade it in with another text. I have made it half working. It changes the text and fade are in and out. But, it does it in a weird order. Here is my code that does the changing:

```
$("header h1").fadeOut(500);
$("#bildfram").css("background-image", "url(" + bilder[bild] + ")" );
$("header h1").text("GeForce | " + text[bild]);
$("header h1").fadeIn(500);
```

That is the order that the code is in. But the execution is a bit weird. On the website the execution is like this:

```
Change background image ($("#bildfram").css("background-image", "url(" + bilder[bild] + ")" );)
Change the text ($("header h1").text("GeForce | " + text[bild]);)
Fade out the text ($("header h1").fadeOut(500);)
Fade in the text ($("header h1").fadeIn(500);)
```

I want the code to be executed in the order that the script is written, FadeOut Text, Change Picture, Change Text, FadeIn Text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change something after `$.fadeOut()` finishes, you need to put the change in a callback of `$.fadeOut()`.

```
$("header h1").fadeOut(500, function() {
  $("#bildfram").css("background-image", "url(" + bilder[bild] + ")" );
  $("header h1").text("GeForce | " + text[bild]);
  $("header h1").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)